# How to fetch over 20000 records from socrata using Http rest call

Tags: c#, soql, socrata

I am fetching records from a private  socrata data set using the http restcall

```
string searchCondition = "resource/xxxx-xxxx.json?$where=column1='something'AND column2='something'&$limit=25000";
 response = client.GetAsync(searchCondition).Result;
```

The problem is that I cannot fetch data more than 20000, it is showing some errors. I learned that using latest 'sodaclient' one could fetch up to 50000 records. Is there any way to achieve this using the http restcall?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about what errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I forgot to add a higher timeout value to 'client'. the operation couldn't complete previously because of it.